# Access the Item bound to a DataGridView Row (WinForms)

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview

How would I access the bound item for a specific row for a DataGridView bound to a Custom Collection?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

MSDN: [DataGridViewRow DataBoundItem Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.databounditem.aspx)

The DataBoundItem property of the DataGridViewRow seems to do the trick!

```
var product = (Product) _grid.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem;
```