# C#: getting the object of the selected cell (linq + entity)

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, entity-framework

i am using the entity framework.

I've a gridview that is binded to an Entity Object.

Like this:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = myEntity.Customer;
```

How can i find out which Customer was selected in the _CellDoubleClick Event.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access the Item bound to a DataGridView Row (WinForms)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182067/access-the-item-bound-to-a-datagridview-row-winforms)

Comment: seems to be what i am looking for.. thank you and sorry that i didnt find it by myself

Comment: it's one of those things that's easy to find when you know what you're looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

One Option is

```
dataGridView1["Customer", e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
```

this is good because if the position of the columns of the grid changes, will
affect the code. And if same is used at many places then you need to change all the occurance.

The above code gives you the value of Customer Column without checking its index in grid.

Nipesh Shah

http://nipeshshah.blogspot.com